# updating an oscillator frequency from out-of-viewController

Tags: ios, swift

In learning iOS i'm making an app that plays tones using AudioKit.io

When the user taps the screen, a new "key" is drawn, and based on its X-position, the frequency of the oscillator is set.

So now I want the user to be able to drag around the "key" and have the frequency of the Oscillator update.

I suppose this is more of a project organization / logical organization question.

There are:

- ViewController.swift (makes oscillators and draws the keys: didTap, toggleSound)
- CircularKeyView.swift (the properties of a circular key: drawRect, didPan, etc)

from CircularKeyView.swift:

```
//PAN IT LIKE u FRYIN.
func didPan(panGR: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

self.superview!.bringSubviewToFront(self)

var translation = panGR.translationInView(self)

self.center.x += translation.x
self.center.y += translation.y


panGR.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self)

//so the coordinates can be updated when there's a pan
self.setNeedsDisplay() //updates the coordinates on a pan event
//updateOscillatorFrequency here?
}
```

from circularKeyView:

```
    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didTap:")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR)


        let mixer = AKMixer(oscillator, osc2)
        AudioKit.output = mixer
        AudioKit.start()
    }

    func didTap(tapGR: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let tapPoint = tapGR.locationInView(self.view)

        let newCircularKey = circularKeyView(origin: tapPoint)

        self.view.addSubview(newCircularKey)
        oscillator.frequency = Double(newCircularKey.center.x) * 2
    }
```

basically, my question is: how  can I tie the behavior of panning to changing a variable (or array/collection of variables) in the viewController?

Comment: I think this is done with delegates .. so I'm learning up on that.  updates to come perhaps

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to update a sound that's playing with an AKPropertySlider. I can get the variables to update, but I can't figure out how to update the sound that's playing.

Comment: @Adrian Hello Adrian it has been a long time since I've looked at the material but yes, it's possible.  You can use the Delegates and Protocol stuff.  Basically the Delegate pattern allows you to create variables that kinda exist globally in your app, and any swift file that implements the "protocol" can access the variable on its changes, iirc.  If you need help with it I'll crack open my old code and take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like it should be your **view controller's responsibility** to create the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, to set it up and add it to your view (here your `CircularKeyView`).

It should also be the target of that Gesture Recognizer, so it can set the view's center in its own coordinate system (it seems really weird that a view updates its own frame). As Apple's View Controller Programing Guide states: "A view controller is responsible for managing its view hierarchy".

Comment: I tried making the pan Gesture live in the viewController, but that's not really how it was laid out in a tutorial I was following. https://www.weheartswift.com/bezier-paths-gesture-recognizers/ I have since found a great example detailing how delegation works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938682/swift-delegate-protocol-structure and I've achieved the desired behavior, where sliding one of the CircularKeyViews (a subview of ViewController) adjusts the oscillator frequency on pan.  The PanGesture lives in the CircularKeysView and a delegate handles the updated information.

Comment: Glad it's working… But I still think you might want to move to a more robust design, where your View Controller is responsible for moving subviews around, attaching and detaching Gesture Recognizers and managing your audio oscillator. Various situations will be hard to handle otherwise: what if you pan out of the View Controller's view bounds? What if two `CircularKeyView`s Gesture Recognizers recognize simultaneously a pan because there overlap each other? And more…

A view should be very agnostic about its environment, and should at most use its `bounds` property, not its `frame`.

Comment: I can add that in some cases, it makes sense for a view to handle Gesture Recognizers: when it is linked with an internal behavior. A good example would be a slider, which is composed of subviews such as the sliding knob. It is sensible to have it manage a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, move the sliding knob and modify its value accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the update! i am still learning and it's fun trying to lay the design out appropriately.  If you could perhaps shed some insight on iOS project organization...: Each key will initiate an oscillator to play a tone.  Now, AudioKit is great but the way it works is that there are oscillators that you link up to AudioKit.output and then you do AudioKit.start() Somehow I need to have all the oscillator objects able to play together, but also be dynamically creatable/destroyable because people can remove circularKeys by tapping them..  does it make sense to use NSMutableSet?

Comment: I don't know much about AudioKit, but your View Controller should, as you say, keep a reference of all playing oscillators. `NSMutableSet` is now a relic of Objective-C era -- now you should instead use a Swift list. Using `var oscillators = [AKOscillators]()` instead of `let` makes it mutable right away, so you can `append(anElement:)` or `removeAtIndex(_:)`.