# Calling a function from one class in another, Xcode error

Tags: swift

I have a View Controller and two classes. Both ClassOne and ClassTwo have a reference to the view controller like so:

```
var viewController: ViewController?
```

Both the view controller and ClassTwo have a `ClassOne` variable that I've assigned like so, in order to retrieve other variables and call functions.

```
let class_one = ClassOne()
```

In `ClassOne`, I am trying to call a function in ClassTwo that uses `class_one` to call functions in ClassOne. For example, in ClassTwo:

```
func changeString() {
    self.class_one.string = "yada yada"
}
```

Here are different ways I have tried to call `changeString()` in `ClassOne`:

```
// Method one:
ClassTwo().changeString()

// Method two:
let class_two = ClassTwo()
self.class_two.changeString()

// Method three:
var class_two: ClassTwo?
self.class_two!.changeString()
```

When I run the app using method one, the app crashes and says the viewController and classOne references in `ClassTwo` are nil.

When I run the app using method two, it crashes and Xcode gives me the following memory warning, citing back and forth errors between the `changeString()` function call in `ClassOne` and my `self.class_one.string` variable call in `ClassTwo`.

```
Xcode memory warning - could not load any Objective-C class information
```

This isn't my actual code, but this is the problem I am facing. I'm a beginner with Swift, and I don't really understand what the difference is in all three of those `ClassTwo` function calls from `ClassOne`.

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How, where and when do you initialize the string variable in ClassOne?

Comment: It is initialized in the class (not a global variable) like so: `var string: String!`

Comment: I guess that is the problem. By creating the class_one you create an instance of class, which haven't initialized its variables yet.

Comment: I am currently learning iOS development and it looks like this is solved through Delegates.  Check out this question about view controllers and passing data between them.. it's the sensible/idiomatic way to have classes talk to the view controller.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222640/passing-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift

Comment: I'm not trying to pass data between the view controller and my two classes, I'm trying to pass data between the two classes... would this approach still work?

Comment: @wasimsandhu Take a look at this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938682/swift-delegate-protocol-structure ..the accepted answer there shows how a delegate is organized: protocol in the swift file but outside / before the class definition, delegate inside where code gets updated/shifts/changes, and another class that "conforms to the protocol" in its signature line, and also a spot where the delegate's protocol functions are implemented.  I believe this approach is very sensible and would make sense for your example as well.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it's impossible to determine the cause for the crashes from the information you've given. You'd have to post you're actual code, in greater detail than you have here.

The reason this is an answer though is because your scenario smacks of bad design. It sounds like you'd benefit from compartmentalising your code.

> Example

If you have a class that is responsible for tracking user location you can instantiate it in your view controller like so:

`let locationTracker = LocationTracker()`

Then lets say that you need to parse the location values into a string you may have another class that is responsible for this:

`let locationParser = LocationParser()`

There is **NO REASON** here for `locationParser` and `locationTracker` to have a reference to each other **OR** the view controller e.g.

```
let location = locationTracker.currentLocation()
let locationAsString = locationParser.parseLocation(location)
```

> Global functions

I hesitate to add this because it can lead to un-maintainable and disorganised code but in swift you can define a function outside of a class. Functions in a class are normally known as methods. When they're outside a class they're known as functions.

So you can have a swift file called `Functions.swift` and simply define:

```
func globalFunc() {

    print("Hello, World!")
}
```

This function cam be called from anywhere in your code.

> Code Design

The way you structure and design your code is very important if you want to create a maintainable and essentially high quality pieces of software.

You'd benefit from reading up about different architectures and tools to help you organise your projects. Like:

[MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)

[MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh848246.aspx)

[Reactive X](http://reactivex.io)

[Dependency Injection](https://www.objc.io/issues/15-testing/dependency-injection/)

MVC is the Apple way, but you benefit from knowledge of other approaches. Also note that the dependency injection article gives `Objective-C` code examples. I know you're learning Swift but if you can it would be good to have a working knowledge of `Objective-C`. Apple's frameworks are still all written in `Objective-C`.

Comment: If I make ClassTwo a global function instead of a method in a class, `self.class_one.string` returns the error: `use of unresolved identifier: "self"`

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to need more. You're giving barely any information. How is `ClassTwo` being used in `self.class_one.string`? If you really want help you'll need to post your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the delegate model, in which case I think you have the optionals going in the wrong direction. You probably want `ClassOne` to definitely have a `ViewController` which it can manipulate as desired. Delegates always control some object, so `ClassOne` should have `var viewController: ViewController`. Not every `ViewController` needs a delegate -- at least, it makes sense to have a  `ViewController` with no delegate (even if the result is a lousy view controller), while a delegate with no `ViewController` to manage is nonsense -- so your `ViewController` should have `var class_one: ClassOne? = nil`. You don't assign `class_one` in initialization because you need the view controller to exist before `ClassOne` may come into existence. Thus you set `class_one` after the view controller is initialized.

I think this may fix your problems by solving some of the internal dependencies. Also, it is not too lengthy a change.